# Material ui chip with the converted date inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, data-conversion

[image]

```
<Chip
        label={`${(<Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{el.from}</Moment>)} - ${(
          <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{el.from}</Moment>
        )}`}
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        size="small"
        icon={<AccessTime />}
        style={{ padding: "4px" }}
      />
```

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kfog4?file=/demo.js)

I have to put inside a `material ui chip`, the start date and the end date, separated by a sign.

Example:

Start date (`DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm`) - End date (`DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm`)

I am using moment for the date conversion.

But I get the type `[obj obj]`.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[material-ui label](https://material-ui.com/api/chip/) expects a node, check out the docs

so we need to pass a node as the label

```
  <Chip
    label={<><Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{el.from}</Moment> - <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{el.from}</Moment></>}
    variant="outlined"
    color="primary"
    size="small"
    icon={<AccessTime />}
    style={{ padding: "4px" }}
  />
```

updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-p1h4o?file=/demo.js)

with your implementation `${(<Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{el.from}</Moment>)}...` component is an object, and when its wrapped around template strings it will print out the [object, object], because object.toString() will call and return [object, object]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

its work

```
   label={
          <>
            <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{el.from}</Moment>
            -
            <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm">{el.from}</Moment>
          </>
        }
```

[image: Edit new]